# Realtime database interaction iOS

Tags: ios, real-time

I am creating an app where a I want a user notified in app whenever anyone they are following posts a picture. So lets say user A follows user B, when user B posts a picture it appears in realtime on user A's screen. My question is: Is this kind of thing done using push notifications? As in make a request to get the image when notification is received or is it better to be using sockets or queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most common use cases for push notifications. Your iOS app asks the user for permission to send notifications, and then registers with Apple to receive push notifications. Apple provides a "token" that is a unique identifier for that notification subscription, which your app will then need to send to your server. When it is time to notify the user about a new photo, or whatever, your server uses Apple's APNS services to send the notification, using the token to identify the recipient.

So, the app and the server use multiple Apple-provided APIs to create the communication *channel*, and then you are free to add whatever logic you want to determine the timing and content of the notifications.

Before trying to implement anything, I'd suggest reading through the entirety of the Apple's [Remote Notifications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/) to a solid understanding of how all the pieces of this technology fit together.

Are there other technologies you could use? Maybe. For iOS apps, Firebase is essentially a more platform-independent wrapper that is built on top of the Apple notification system described above; under the hood, it is still using APNS and requires some of the same initial steps to configure your app. Socket-type technologies could be ok for limited use cases but aren't the correct approach for general purpose notification delivery, due to restrictions with running the app in the background (among other reasons).

Answer (score 1):

For realtime actions like that you may use **google's firebase**
also you may use **push notifications** to send the model which may contain a url of the image and when received load the image and display it,Also same functionality can be accomplished with **socketIO**